# treeview change place after checking node

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

i have an asp.net treeView.
 on node expanded i'm binding child nodes for the expanded node.
But if i check the node and than expand it, the node and all it's child change there  position  and become like childs to the main node. when clicking again on the + it takes the right place.
Any idea on how to solve it!!!

that's the tree in an updatePanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TreeView ID="MyTreeView" runat="server" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" NodeIndent="15"
    OnTreeNodeExpanded="MyTreeView_TreeNodeExpanded">
    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px"
        NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
        VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>

        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

from the code behind:
on page load i have :

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.MyTreeView.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.All;
                this.MyTreeView.ShowLines = true;
                FillTree();//custom method just to fill the tree
            }
```

and

```
    protected void MyTreeView_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode expandedNode = e.Node;

        if (expandedNode.Value != "-1" && expandedNode.Value == "-2")
        {
            //Some logic
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this JavaScript function fix the tree :

```
function FixTreeview(treeView) {
            try {
                if (treeView) {
                    var treeLinks = treeView.getElementsByTagName("a");
                    var nodeCount = treeLinks.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
                        if (treeLinks[i].firstChild.tagName) {
                            if (treeLinks[i].firstChild.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
                                var currentToggleLink = treeLinks[i];
                                var childContainer = GetParentByTagName("table", currentToggleLink).nextSibling;
                                try {
                                    eval(currentToggleLink.href);
                                } catch (e) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
```